# Using regex to extract two words from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have tried to look at several examples but can't figure out how or what the best way to get two values from strings like this:

```
setEditMode                                    | Ändringsläge
```

I can get the first value but how do I get the second one after the "|" ?

I have tried using Pattern and Matcher and also using split().

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Temp\\translate\\en.lang"));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] values = line.split("\\|");
                String v1 = values[0];
                String v2 = values[1];
                System.out.println(v2);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

When just printing "line" in the System.out i get:

```
archiveLoad                                      | Loading archives
archiveLoadCount                                 | Archives uploaded:
archiveLoadStage                                 | Stage:
archiveLoadFilesCount                            | Files uploaded:
archiveLoadElapsedTime                           | Time elapsed:
archiveLoadInit                                  | Initialization
archiveLoadUndeletableIntervals                  | Loading undeletable intervals
archiveLoadDb                                    | Loading from database
archiveLoadDisk                                  | Loading from disk
archiveLoadProblemIntervals                      | Loading data about problems
```

Comment: Please provide some code what you tried and ask the question. This is way too broad to guess and asnwer.

Comment: System.out.println(line.split("\\|")[0]);

Comment: Try `split("\\s+\\|\\s+")`...

Comment: Could you add examples of desired output?

Comment: In the first line of the example I want: "archiveLoad" and                                 "Loading archives" and same pattern for all other lines.

Comment: Ahhhh!!, Sorry I just noticed that the first line in the file was different and did not match the rest. All working now, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split, as you shown in a comment

```
String line = "aaaa |  aaaa";
String[] values = line.split("\\|");
String v1 = values[0];
String v2 = values[1];
```

You can also use a regex that captures twice all but `|`: `([^|]+)|([^|]+)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have tried all suggested answers and none of them work when I try them in java.

Comment: I've fixed typos one. What kind of issues you had with them? Errors or invalid results?

Comment: And now I've fully fixed the first example.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want your output, but it can easily be done using something like:

`([a-zA-ZåäöÖÄÅ]+|[a-zA-ZåäöÖÄÅ]+)`.

which will match all letter, including åäö/ÅÄÖ. Add 0-9 to your regex to also match numbers:

(`([0-9a-zA-ZåäöÖÄÅ]+|[0-9a-zA-ZåäöÖÄÅ]+)`)

Live example: http://rubular.com/r/xMZ1na9r0q

Comment: Thanks, it works when I test it in a regex-tester but not in my java-code. Why does it not work? System.out.println(line.split("([0-9a-zA-ZåäöÖÄÅ]+|[0-9a-zA-ZåäöÖÄÅ]+)")[0]);

Comment: Unfortunately I do not code in Java, and can't really offer any helpful advice with that. Hopefully someone else can offer some expertise in that area. Do you get any error messages?